# H0w to find the centre of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've attached the the question because I'm awful with Latex.[image]

Interpreting this, does zr=rz mean that the matrix at this centre we're trying to find, is commutative to all other matrices in this ring?

My friend has shown me his solution though I'm not entirely convinced because I've found an example of his matrix where it doesn't commute with another matrix in the ring. Here is his answer. Is he correct?

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the given solution is incorrect. But the correct solution will be a subset of the claimed solution.

Comment: I'm confused. The correct solution will be a subset of this solution? If so, which is the right one...

Comment: I mean that the center of the ring will be a subset of the the one claimed to be the center in that solution.

Comment: The fact that Latex you are awful with Latex(why?) does not mean you can break the rules of this site. They were created for a reason. If you do not want to devote a time to write decent post why would anyone devote his time to answer the question? If you are not able to understand simple mathematical notation (Latex) how are you supposed to understand answer to mathematical question?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm sorry I'm still not following. Does that mean the solution here is incorrect, and the correct center is a smaller subset of the solution here?

Comment: Yes, was that not what I said?

Comment: @Trismegistos I'm sorry, I'm not hurting anyone, and I din't know. What reason is that exactly? 

And understanding Latex and understanding ring theory are obviously independent. Whys is this post supposedly 'indecent'? I'm just trying to acquire mathematical knowledge quickly. And that won't happen if I'm slaving away trying to figure out how to write it correctly, so sorry.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah.. I now see that you did say 'the given solution is INCORRECT'... I misread that, I apologise. I thought so. How do I arrive at the correct solution from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Choose any matrix:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
that belongs to the center. Then in particular, $A$ must commute with the two given matrices in the hint. This yields two matrix equations, which yield constraints on $a,b,c,d$. These constraints are necessary conditions for $A$ to belong to the center. You will then need to show that these constraints are also sufficient by showing that all matrices that satisfy these constraints must commute with any other matrix.

Comment: Thanks that makes a bit of sense. you say A must commute with the two given matrices in the hint, is this because A must commute with EVERY matrix in R, or am I wrong in saying that?
I'm not sure what TWO equations you get... and what the constraints are.

Comment: You are correct. Call the two given matrices in the hint $B$ and $C$. Then our two matrix equations are $AB = BA$ and $AC = CA$. Multiply everything out, then equate their corresponding entries.

Comment: Ah, you genius, thanks a lot! So I must show AB=BA and AC=CA, I understand that. But what am I doing by equating their corresponding entries..?

Comment: I get:

$AB = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} = BA = \begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Two matrices are equal iff their corresponding entries are equal. So we get that $0 = c$, $a = d$, $0 = 0$, $c = 0$. This tells us that $A$ has the form:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
d & b \\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now do the same thing for the other matrix equation.